# Using Python Panda's to fill new table with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I've imported data from a csv file which has columns NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE_NUMBER.
Sometimes, at least 1 of the columns has a missing value for that row. e.g

```
0 - Bill, Flat 2, 555123
1 - Katie, NaN, NaN
2 - Ruth, Flat 1, ?
```

I'm trying to get the NaN values to fill a new table which I can do if a filler value has been put in such as:
`newDetails = details [details['PHONE_NUMBER']=="?"]`
which gives me:

```
2 - Ruth, Flat 1, ?
```

I tried to use `fillna` but I couldn't find the syntax that would work.

Comment: Can you post what the desired output should be as you've not explained what the missing values should be filled with, also are you asking how to replace `?` with `NaN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas `fillna` ([`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)) is quite simple. Suppose your data frame is `df`. Here's how you can do.

```
df.fillna('_missing_value_', inplace=True)
```

It looks like you have different fields with missing value. May be try this:

```
df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)),'_missing_value_')
```

**Edit1 to replace in a column**

If you want to replace a column Flat 2, here's how:

```
col_flat = df[['Flat 2']].fillna('?')
df['Flat 2'] = col_flat['Flat 2']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This kinda worked but it replaced all of the NaN values in every column rather than ones in a specific column.

Also, for some reason, I have longer numbers such as 140191 which are now being shown as 1.40191e+06