# Print table with NaN values from given dataset and later print with Predicted values using Pandas or Recsys

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with 100k Movie Lens [dataset](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k.zip), I need to print the entire Table of `u.data` with NaN values and once again with predicted values. Pandas or Recsys are suitable, others too are welcomed though.

```
data = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.data', sep='\t')
print data
```

The above code doesn't provide the needful output, since it prints only first and last 30 records. Moreover, I need it foll. format

```
UserID <MovieID>1   <MovieID>2 <MovieID>3
    1   <Rating>5         NaN          3 
    2        NaN            2          1
```

I've already been through

1. [This 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890736/using-python-pandas-to-fill-new-table-with-nan-values) SF Question similar
2. [This 2](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/12-pandas-techniques-python-data-manipulation/) Example from AnalyticsVidhya

Comment: Hello @jezrael I just followed your answer from a link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861846/convert-row-to-column-in-python-pandas) Although I haven't found the correct answer. I feel you can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you were asking but:

To print column names and have UserID as the index just use:

```
data = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.data', sep='\t', names=['UserID','MovieID_1','MovieID_2','MovieID_3']).set_index('UserID')
```

while for printing the whole dataframe there was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124601/is-there-a-way-to-pretty-print-the-entire-pandas-series-dataframe), where it was suggested to use the option_context from pandas:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(data)
```